# What are form factories and when should they be used?

Tags: django, django-forms

Would someone like to attempt a succinct explanation of what a form_factory, or a modelform_factory is in relation to a form / modelform?

- Why use a factory?
- Is there an official technical definition for a
  factory method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `modelform_factory` method is a method that returns a `ModelForm` class. Here's an example of why it's useful.

If you have a simple view that uses a form for a single model, then there is no need for a factory, you can simply define the form:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product

def add_product_view(request):
    form = ProductForm()
    ...
```

However, if your view needs to handle multiple models, then you might not want to have to define a form class for every model. The `modelform_factory` lets you create the form class dynamically.

```
apps.get_model('newapp', 'mymodel')

def add_model_view(request, model_name):
    Model = apps.get_model('myapp', model_name)
    Form = modelform_factory(Model)
```

The Django admin uses `modelform_factory` to generate model form classes dynamically. This means you don't need to define a model form every time you register a model in the Django admin.